error while generating pdf output from xdocreport (able to generate odt)
I am running Tomcat 10 with Java 23. My code is able to generate the target odt file,but failing to generate target pdf file. I am using below libraries & code and pasted the error below. please help me.
libraries

itext-2.1.7.jar

java-rdfa-0.4.2.jar

jena-core-5.2.0.jar

jena-iri-5.2.0.jar

odfdom-java-0.12.0.jar

slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar

velocity-engine-core-2.4.1.jar

xdocreport-2.1.0.jar

xerces-2.4.0.jar

xercesImpl.2.12.2.jar


java (servlet) code
import java.io.*;
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;
import javax.naming.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.XDocReportException;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.IXDocReport;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.registry.XDocReportRegistry;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.ConverterTypeTo;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.ConverterTypeVia;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.Options;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.XDocConverterException;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.IContext;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.TemplateEngineKind;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.formatter.FieldsMetadata;
import fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.document.DocumentKind;

public class odtReportViewer extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

    try {
      InputStream infile = new FileInputStream(path+rname);
      IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(infile, TemplateEngineKind.Velocity);
      IContext context = report.createContext();
      context.put("name", "tester");
      OutputStream outfile = new FileOutputStream(new File("outfile.odt"));
      report.process(context, outfile); //this is working perfectly

      OutputStream outfile1 = new FileOutputStream(new File("outfile.pdf"));
      Options options = Options.getFrom(DocumentKind.ODT).to(ConverterTypeTo.PDF).via(ConverterTypeVia.ODFDOM);
      report.convert(context, options, outfile1); //this is giving problem and generating zero size pdf file
    } catch (Exception e) { out.println(e.getMessage()); e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
}

runtime error
fr.opensagres.odfdom.converter.core.ODFConverterException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.manifest.OdfFileEntry.getEncryptionData()" because "manifestEntry" is null
I want my code to generate the target PDF file
